# Change an image when input is given

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small basic html code with JavaScript . All I want is when I type 3,it should show me an image as specified and for 9 accordingly. This is the demo. Visit http://jsbin.com/UVOFeGIG/1/edit

Its working there. I don't know why the JavaScript doesn't work this way. Can anyone figure this out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var num2img = {
  "3":"visa",
  "9":"mastercard"
};

$('#num').on('input', function(){
  var val = this.value;
  if(val.length<=1){
     var n = this.value.charAt(0);
     if(val && num2img[n]!==undefined){
       $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/eee&text='+ num2img[n] +'.png';
     }else{
       $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/cf5';
     }
  }
});

</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Demo by Roko C.B.</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input id="num"><br>
  <img id="cardImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/cf5">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var num2img = {
  "3":"visa",
  "9":"mastercard"
};

    $('#num').keyup(function(){
      var val = this.value;
      if(val.length<=1){
         var n = this.value.charAt(0);
         if(val && num2img[n]!==undefined){
           $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/eee&text='+ num2img[n] +'.png';
         }else{
           $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/cf5';
         }
      }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc76h/9/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried this.The problem is,the code is working in the jsfiddle,I mean when I use it in an html page,this doesnt work

Comment: yes add it ur code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..your codes });`

Comment: Ya i have done that too.Here is where I uploaded it http://izwipe.com/change/  check this,even when I type anything,it just show me the default image

Comment: can you tell me,why it worked this way and not the code I made?

Comment: you have to call your function on dom ready, then key up activity will send data to function every value you type so its works

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$(function(){

    // you have not given any event
    $('#num').on('keyup', function(){
      var val = this.value;
      if(val.length){//your length checking logically wrong
         var n = this.value.charAt(0);
         if(val && num2img[n]!==undefined){
           $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'data/1357696142_mastercard1'+ num2img[n] +'.gif';
         }else{
           $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/cf5';
         }
      }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the $('#cardImage')[0]  to  $('#cardImage').attr('src' , 'http://placehold.it/100x100/eee&text='+ num2img[n] +'.png');  as # will return one element replace  See the jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/dMWmw/

```
var num2img = {
  "3":"visa",
  "9":"mastercard"
};

$('#num').on('input', function(){
  var val = this.value;
  if(val.length<=1){
     var n = this.value.charAt(0);
     if(val && num2img[n]!==undefined){
       $('#cardImage').attr('src' , 'http://placehold.it/100x100/eee&text='+ num2img[n] +'.png');
     }else{
       $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/cf5';
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place you script code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code goes here
});
```

and replace

```
$('#cardImage')[0].src = 'data/1357696142_mastercard1'+ num2img[n] +'.gif';
```

by

```
$('#cardImage')[0].src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/eee&text='+ num2img[n] +'.gif';
```

Comment: Ya there was a syntax error in what I wrote.The demo was correct.I did this way,but it wont work.check http://izwipe.com/change/ where I uploaded this

Comment: your path to image was wrong initially,  and about "$(document).ready(function(){     //your code goes here
});" block - your code executed as soon as it saw script when nothing was present on the client side. When same code executed inside ready block the execution is delayed till complete DOM is formed and hence it finds the elements. The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. read more on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

try capturing "keypress" event on input box, http://api.jquery.com/keypress/  OR
try capturing "change" event on input box, http://api.jquery.com/change/